# Java, EJB, Concurrency lock for all methods

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, ejb

I have EJB with two methods

```
@Singleton(name = "RatingCalculatorEJB")
public class RatingCalculatorBean {

    public void countRating() {}

    public void countRating(int someID) {}
}
```

By default all methods has concurrency lock: @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
If method invoked by any thread - another thread will wait to invoke this method.

But I need more - if any method invoked by a thread, all other threads that call **any** method of EJB should wait.
Does I have any way to do it?

The same question for @Stateless beans

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Lock(LockType.WRITE) locks ALL EJB methods of the bean, so it already does what you want.

Stateless beans only handle one client at a time, so concurrency should rarely be a problem there.

Comment: @Singleton stateless beans can commonly handle more then one client at a time which is what the OP is using.

Comment: If you have a stateless @Singleton bean you should probably refactor it to a stateless session bean instead, though. :) Otherwise, use @Lock(LockType.READ).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make that method synchronized. In that way only one thread can access the method at one time.

Comment: I think the accepted answer is a bit better because @Lock is a container construct and as such will play correctly in the managed environment (clustered etc). Hand synchronizing, while it may work, is a non container aware approach and might have negative or unintended consequences in that environment.

Answer (score -1):

`@Lock(LockType.WRITE)` on bean won't lock all methods of the bean. It is same as put `@Lock(LockType.WRITE)` on each method of the bean.

Annotating a singleton class with `@Lock` specifies that all the business methods and any timeout methods of the singleton will use the specified lock type unless they explicitly set the lock type with a method-level `@Lock` annotation. If no `@Lock` annotation is present on the singleton class, the default lock type, `@Lock(WRITE)`, is applied to all business and timeout methods.